# Select Json string with Select

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have following statement that I am trying to execute in Sql Server 2016 CTP 3:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

set @json = '[ 
   { "name": "John" },
   { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Doe" }
]'

select
    'othervalue' as o,
    @json as j
for json path
```

The problem is when I execute these statements I get the following Json string (with escaped characters):

```json
[{"o":"othervalue","j":"[ \r\n   { \"name\": \"John\" },\r\n   { \"name\": \"Jane\", \"surname\": \"Doe\" }\r\n]"}]
```

My question is how can select a Json string with a select statement correctly (without escaped characters).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap @json variable with JSON_QUERY:

```sql
select
     'othervalue' as o,
      JSON_QUERY(@json) as j
for json path
```

See frequently asked questions on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631706.aspx